# How to expand an array?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to programming but trying to do the following:

I have an array of time `x=[12,18,27,34]` with corresponding flux values in array `y=[34,68,22,81]`. I have expanded x so that the new array `(x_new)` adds 1 from `xmin` to `xmax`.

`x_new=[np.min(x)+i for i in range(0,np.max(x)-np.min(x)+1)]`

I want to expand my flux array so that it is the same length as `x_new` but I need the original values in identical index positions as the original x values. What can be input into the spare points of my expanded flux array can be anything.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] Just got what you are expecting. Please try the following:

```
import numpy as np

x=[12,18,27,34]  # array of time
y=[34,68,22,81]  # corresponding flux values

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    x_new=[np.min(x)+i for i in range(0,np.max(x)-np.min(x)+1)]
    y_new = []

    for i in xrange(len(x_new)):
        if x_new[i] in x:
                y_new.append(y[x.index(x_new[i])])
        else:
                y_new.append(np.nan)

    print 'x_new = ', x_new
    print 'y_new = ', y_new
```

Output:

```
x_new =  [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
y_new =  [34, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 68, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 22, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 81]
```

Comment: That is really useful but not quite the final result I'm looking for.  x_new is correct and I do need them both the same length but I need y_new to be the following: 

y_new =  [34, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 68, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 22, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 81]

so my original y flux values still coincide with the positions of the original x values in x_new. All other values in y_new can be a nan.

@ccf

Comment: If either can help that would be great (forgot to tag in the first reply). @Arman

Comment: That is perfect. Cheers for the help! @ccf